# allocating memory for list - Python

Tags: python, list, memory, malloc, allocation

I have a small problem. How do I allocate some memory for a list.
Let's say it'll have 4 elements, but this code gives error that it can't assign to operator.

```
char *buf1 = int* PyMem_New(int, 4)
```

Maybe it's late, but I need it for my college assignment.

THANK YOU very much!

Comment: First, your code is not valid code, it should be char buf1 = PyMem_New(int, 4). But it is not clear to me what you are trying to do: do you want to create a python list ? In that case, you must use the list API from python. If you want to create a list in C (of C integers), why do you use the python C API at all ?

Comment: Are you writing in python or C? It seems like you're mixing syntax and programming styles.

If you're working in python, whats the context? Does it really matter if the list initializes to size 4? Why can't you just use a standard python list? 'a = list()'

Answer (score 1):

[`PyList_New()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html#PyList_New) allows you to specify an initial size in the single mandatory argument. Don't forget to actually set the items with [`PyList_SetItem()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/list.html#PyList_SetItem) before using the list in Python code though.

Comment: well, the problem is I need to reserve computer memory for N integers. (N is calculated in process). And the assignment says to allocate required memory. I'm writing the program in python, but "char buf1 = PyMem_New(int, 4)" throws an error. I did the program using list.append(), and I can reserve memory by creating list with N elements of None. But I think that's not it. Can you write me that little code using PyMem_New or PyMem_Malloc? I can't get it to work. Thank's again for all the reply's :D

Answer (score 0):

I believe buf1 needs to be a pointer.

```
char *buf1 = PyMem_New(int, 4);
```